# Wrong og:image is appearing on page metadata

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo, facebook-opengraph

In my `[id].tsx` page I have the following meta tag structure

```
<Head>
  <meta property="og:title" content={'품고 - ' + archive.title} key="title" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="article" key="type" />
  {imageUrl && <meta property="og:image" content={imageUrl} key="image" />}
</Head>
```

However in my production server, when I scrape an article using the Facebook debugger I get the following error

[image]

But when I check for an article in my development server, the proper image shows even though the code is the same as production

[image]

I also do have the following line in my `_app.tsx` file that I think may be causing the error but am not sure

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://poomgo.com/" />
```

And the truly strange thing is that if I share my production article links on kakao, the thumbnail image shows up fine, but on Facebook and LinkedIn, the thumbnail image does not show up properly.

Does anyone know why my meta tags are scraped differently on my production and development servers when the code applied is exactly the same?

---

How my imageUrl is generated

I get `archive` data from a third party API (strapi) using `useSWR`

```
const { data: archive, error } = useSWR('/archives/' + router.query.id, (url) => {
    return axios.get(url).then(res => res.data)
  }, {
    initialData: props.data
  })
```

I then get my `images` from the `archives` and if `images` exist, I get my `imageUrl`

```
const images = archive.images
  let imageUrl = ''

  if (images && images.length > 0) {
    imageUrl = getCloundFrontUrl(images[0].url)
  }
```

I then use the `getCloundFrontUrl` function to replace the url with my cdn

```
export const getCloundFrontUrl = (url) => {
  return url ? url.replace('poomgo-homepage.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com', 'cdn-hp.poomgo.com') : ''
}
```

Below is the shape of my data

[image]

Comment: The error indicates that you're providing a relative URL to the `og:image` tag for that specific article. Are you certain all the URLs you pass to `imageUrl` are absolute URLs? How is that URL generated?

Comment: @juliomalves edited my post to show how I get my `imageUrl`, I believe I am showing my URLs as abosolute URLs, is there a way I might be providing relative URLs based on what I showed in my edit?

Comment: It could be relative if the URL value you get from the API (`images[0].url`) is itself relative. You could check if the URLs begin with `http` in them, that would probably ensure they're absolute.

Comment: console logging the `images[0].url` gives me an absolute URL that starts with a `https`. But I found out that my homepage `og:image` has a relative URL of 

`<meta property="og:image" content="/static/images/thumbnail.png" />` perhaps that is somehow causing the problem?

Comment: Does that mean the homepage's `og:image` is appearing on the article's metadata? Is that because the article itself doesn't have a `imageUrl`?

Comment: @juliomalves yes and only on the production server and not on development. And that's what confounds me. The article itself has an `imageUrl`, but for whatever reason it is using the homepage's `og:image` only on production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://poomgo.com/" />
```

from my `_app.tsx` and the issue was resolved. Pretty sure that the code above signalled redirects to my home page from every page on production which caused the wrong `og:image`